# Issue with Building swift file from PWABuilder

Tags: ios, swift, progressive-web-apps

I'm having an issue with trying to build a file I downloaded from PWABuilder.
The error I'm getting is: Value of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'underPageBackgroundColor'

Heres the snippet:

```
  if #available(iOS 15.0, *), adaptiveUIStyle {
        themeObservation = OVATION.webView.observe(\.underPageBackgroundColor) { [unowned self] webView, _ in
            currentWebViewTheme = OVATION.webView.underPageBackgroundColor.isLight() ?? true ? .light : .dark
            self.overrideUIStyle()
```

As I downloaded it from PWABuilder, it should just build fine, so not sure why I'm getting this error. I don't know swift, so not entirely sure why it's happening. I've followed the article [here](https://docs.pwabuilder.com/#/builder/app-store) but doesnt make any mention. Any thoughts would be great.